# Why is the data write not reflected to the file using fprintf file stream

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *logh;

    logh = fopen("/home/user1/data.txt", "a+");

    if (logh == NULL)
    {
        printf("error creating file \n");
        return -1;
    }

    // write some data to the log handle and check if it gets written..
    int result = fprintf(logh, "this is some test data \n");
    if (result > 0)
        printf("write successful \n");
    else
        printf("couldn't write the data to filesystem \n");

    while (1) {
    };

    fclose(logh);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this program, i see that the file is getting created but it does not contain any data. what i understand i that there is data caching in memory before the data is actually written to the filesystem to avoid multiple IOs to increase performance. and I also know that i can call fsync/fdatasync inside the program to force a sync. but can i force the sync from outside without having to change the program?

I tried running `sync` command from Linux shell but it does not make the data to appear on the file. :(

Please help if anybody knows any alternative to do the same.

One useful information: I was researching some more on this and finally found this, to remove internal buffering altogether, the `FILE` mode can be set to `_IONBF` using `int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size)`

Comment: fflush(logh); man fflush

Comment: Also, always check the return value of fopen().

Comment: yeah thanks, i know about them but is there any way to do it without having to change the program. i mean flushing the process's all file data caching to filesystem from a shell command or something

Comment: No way without changing the program .. when it performs `while(1)` the data to be written is still in the program's memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IO functions using`FILE` pointers cache the data to be written in an internal buffer within the program's memory until they decide to perform a system call to 'really' write it (which is for normal files usually when the size of the data cached reaches `BUFSIZ`). 
Until then, there is no way to force writing from outside the progam.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your program does not close the file because of your `while` statement. Remove these lines:

```
while (1) {
    };
```

If the intent is to wait forever, then close the file with `fclose` before executing the `while` statement.

Comment: The while loop is written on purpose so that while the program is still running, the writes should sync without closing the file handle. if i close the file handle before while loop then the writes would happen automatically but what i don't understand is why the data write is not happening after long time also

Comment: i mean its quite possible that you write some data to a file stream and then get busy doing some processing for a long time before closing the file stream explicitly. in the meanwhile, the data should synchronize with file system, right?

Comment: You have to either `fflush` or `fclose`. That's fairly common. The software is not going to know when to send the data.

Comment: but isn't there any hook similar to how `open()` has `O_SYNC` to sync the data automatically after each `write()` operation?

Comment: You are not writing anything. The buffer is just filling up.

Comment: And knowing is half the battle!

Comment: Just to inform you, I finally found a way to achieve a synchronous way to write using `FILE` streams using `int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size)` to set the buffer mode to `_IONBF` :)

Comment: Correct, forgot about that function. My point in your original code still stands, however.

Comment: yep. that's there :-)